# CoreData NSFetchResult issue

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have an extraordinary issue with composing proper NSPredicate.
I have the following model structure (just a piece of relevant model shown)
[image]

As you can see there are four AttributeValue entities inherited from parent entity. Now I need to perform the request using predicate.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY attributeValues.value = %@",@"Certain value"];

[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

and of course this request causes the exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath attributeValues.value not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Entity id=11>'
***
```

because base entity really doesn't have `value` attribtue. Is there a way to bypass the situation? I need to populate data exactly this way from Entity side.

Comment: Having attribute 'value' in all subentities, why do you not want to add this attribute to superentity 'AttributeValue'?

Comment: It's not shown on the schema, but all descendants have value attribute of different data type depending on symantic: string, integer, float, binary. I'd like to have value in base entity, but it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing an entity of type `AttributeValue`. This entity has a `value` field, but it is not clear from the schema of what type it is or what it refers to. I don't think you can meaningfully repeat the same attribute name in the child entities.

If you want to reference a string you will have to connect the `AttributeValueString` entity to your `Entity` entity through a relationship. You cannot use the parent entity as a "catch-all". Child entities inherit the attributes from their parent, but are not used instead of relationships. (You might be confused because of the pretty arrows in the schema view of the model ;-).

So in your case you would need four distinct relationships from your `Entity` entity in order to represent all value types.

Let me suggest a different setup. It is more feasible, IMHO, to add the appropriate attributes to the `AttributeValue` class itself and do away with the child entities. You can always leave the unused ones empty. You can even add a `type` property (some kind of enum) that indicates the type if you want.

```
AttributeValue
|_____ stringValue
|_____ integerValue
|_____ doubleValue
|_____ binaryValue
|_____ type
```

This appears to be a much more robust and manageable setup.

In your predicate, you will have to **explicitly state which data type you are querying**. This seems to make sense also from the point of view of good programming practice.